# Probability of one number being a part of another

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Say I have a 4 digit number A such as $1234$. I would like to know what's the probability of it being 'inside' of randomly chosen number B. Example:

number $A = 1234$ is a part of number $B = 5612348$.

Length of $B$ would also be random. I believe the answer is $(n+1-4) : 10^n$, $n$ being the length of $B$, and $4$ is just the length of $A$, because there could be $10^n$ possible $B$ numbers of length $n$, and I can position number $A$ in $n+1-4$ ways. Am I correct?

Comment: does A or B or both have repeated digits? that's an important point you did not specify.

Comment: @GCab Exactly .. I've been trying to make this point in my Answer ... and subsequent comments back and forth with OP :)

Comment: sorry I just don't think I understand the multiple-counting (I have no idea how to get the formula). A and B are absolutely random.

Comment: @MateuszSowiński Well, I think you see that you get double-counting ... but as to how to get the right formula ... that's not easy ... I wouldn't know how to do it myself.  It's possible some better mathematicians might have a good trick ... but I wouldn't be surprised if this exact function turns out to be too nasty .. and that some approximation is called for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. After positioning $A$, you can fill up the other digits to get $B$ in many more ways.

For example: $A=1234$, and $n=5$. Then your formula says that there are $5+1-4=2$ ways to position $A$ (which is correct, since you either start with $1234$ or end with $1234$), but there are more than $2$ numbers out of all $10^5$ that include $A$: $12341, 12342, 12343, ... , 11234, 212234, 31234$ etc.

Now, from this example, the fix *seems* easy: just multiply by $10^{n-4}$. That is, there are $10$ numbers starting with $1234$, and $10$ numbers ending with $1234$, so that gives you $20$ numbers total, rather than $2$. Or, in general: there are $n-4$ digits left to be filled in after positioning $A$, so there are $10^{n-4}$ ways to do this.

However, what if you have repeating patterns?  For example, what if $A=1111$? Then the $20$ would double-count the $11111$.  Likewise, what if $A=1234$ and $n=8$ ... then you would double-count $12341234$.  And with longer and longer strings, you end up over-counting more and more. So example, $11111111$ will count $1111$ five times.

I don't think it will be easy to take account all these kinds of over-counting: much depends on the nature of $A$. For example, if $A=3143$, then you have an overlapping $3$ (so, e.g. $3143143$ counts $A$ twice), but with $A=1414$, then $B=14141414$ will count $A$ three times. And depending on the length of $B$, you may not be able to 'fit' overlapping ot repeating $A$'s in there some nice number of times.

So, I think the exact formula may end up being quite, quite nasty.

Comment: I believe the formula is `10^(n-4) * (n + 1 - 4) / 10^n` then? I don't care about repeating patterns

Comment: oh no wait this is incorrect, give me a second

Comment: @MateuszSowiński  I understand that you are fine with $1234$ being inside $12341234$ ... but my point is that if you consider the $10^4$ numbers that start with $1234$, as well as the $10^4$ numbers that end with $1234$, then you just double-counted the $12341234$. So, there are not $2*10^4$ of those numbers, but rather $2*10^4-1$.

Comment: Okay, let's omit the repeating patterns for now. What's wrong with my formula? number B must have `n-4` random digits hence the `10^(n-4)` and I multiply that by `(n + 1 - 4)` because the A can be placed in that many ways? When I plug in various numbers the probability is sometimes greater than 1...

Comment: @MateuszSowiński How is that possible?  With $10^{n-4}$ in the numerator, and $10^n$ in the denominator, you end up diving $n+1-4$ by $10^4$ ... no way that ends up being greater than $1$ ... unless $n$ is *really* big (loike n=10^4$)... but with *really* big $n$, you get *lots* of double-counting (and triple counting, etc.) . So, the problem is problem-counting yet again

Comment: Example: A is length 3 and B is length 1000 in base-2. The formula is then $2^{B-A} * (B + 1 - A) : (2^B) = 2^{997}*998 : 2^{1000} = 499:4 > 1$ did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: @MateuszSowiński No, you didn't make a mistake. But note that you had to pick a really long string in order to get this weird result.  And hence you get lots of double-counting. And especially with base 2 you get a high fraction of repeats among the numbers.  So what your example shows is exactly what I have been saying:  your formula gets the wrong answer, because it doesn't take into account double-counting.

Comment: Right right, I didn't think it would have so much of an impact...

Comment: @MateuszSowiński With those lengths, it does: take your example: say $A=101$. Then think of how many times you'd get $101$ in a random 1000-digit $B$, like $11101010010101000011101100101...$.  There, I already see it 6 times, and I'm only 25 digits in .... So your formula could count the same $B$ hundreds of times

Comment: Alright, but still I can't wrap my head around the correct formula then..